# MongoDB check if id is a valid BSON PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

How do I check if a MongoDB id is a valid BSON?

This is what I have at the moment

```
public function findOne($id=""){
  if($BSON_id = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($id)){
    $user = $this->collection->findOne([
     '_id'=> new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($id)
   ]);
   if(!$user){ return false; }
   return $user;
  }
}

(new User)->findOne("invalidBson123")
```

However, the above throws an fatal error:

> Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error
>   parsing ObjectId string

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-bson-objectid.construct.php reads:

> id (string)
>
> A 24-character hexadecimal string. If not provided, the driver will generate an ObjectId.

So the check can be a simple regex:

```
if(preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]{24}$/i', $id) === 1) {
.....
```

Or if you prefer to stick to ObjectId constructor and make it future-proof, do it with try-catch:

```
try {
    $user = $this->collection->findOne([
     '_id'=> new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId($id)
   ]);
   if(!$user){ return false; }
   return $user;
} catch() {}
```

Comment: Thanks! I decided to go a bit more simpler and use `strlen()`

Comment: `It must be a hexadecimal string. "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw" will pass the strlen check and still throw the exception.` Thanks Alex. So using `strlen()` won't work here

Comment: small thing.. `preg_match` returns number of matches (not boolean) so `!== false` will always be true

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Alex for pointing out that a MongoDB ObjectId is a 24-character hexadecimal string.

So, now all I had to do is check if its a hexadecimal and its length is 24.

```
if(strlen($id) == "24" && ctype_xdigit($id)){
  // Its a valid BSON
  // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: It must be a **hexadecimal** string. "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvw" will pass the `strlen` check and still throw the exception.