# Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error parsing ObjectId string:

Tags: php, html, mongodb, error-handling

I was trying to create a project using MongoDB and PHP .
I created a table and inserted all data .
Now I want to delete the record using delete button and I inserted delete link in each row.
I linked it to delete.php which contains following code.

```
<?php 
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$conn=new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db=$conn->project;
$collection=$db->notes;

try{
$id =new  MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($id);
$collection->deleteOne(array('_id'=>$id ));
header('location:real.php');
}
catch(Expection $e){}
?>
```

But now I am getting this error

```
Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: Error parsing ObjectId string: in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\delete.php:9 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\delete.php(9): MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId->__construct('') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mongo\delete.php on line 9
```

My index.php contains following code

```
<div method="post">

        <table style="width:50%" border="solid">
          <tr>
            <th>_id</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Difficulty</th>
            <th>Related Topics</th>
            <th>Action</th>
          </tr>

        <?php
        
        $collection = $db->notes;
        $data = $collection->find();
        foreach($data as $document){
         ?> 
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $document['_id'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $document['author'] ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $document["subject"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $document["title"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $document["notes"] ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $document["difficulty"] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $document["rel_topic"] ?></td> 
            <td><a href='delete.php?id=<?php $document['_id'];?>'>Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        
    </div>
```

Please Help me!! I am new to PHP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB check if id is a valid BSON PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49298150/mongodb-check-if-id-is-a-valid-bson-php)

Comment: I tried everything suggested in above link. Still its now working

Comment: What is the value of `$id` when you set it from `$_GET`?

Comment: Looks like the $id is an empty string.

Comment: Yes $id is showing empty, but where did I went wrong??